# Can't switch branches - "Error: Untracked working tree files..." should I do git add?

Tags: git

I have this on my **.gitignore** file:

```
/nbproject/
/app/runtime/
/app/runtime/application.log*
/app/runtime/error.log*
/app/config/localdev.php*
.DS_Store
```

1)
I have checkout to **master branch** and then, checkout again, back to **dev branch**.

2)
Once I got back to **dev branch**, I lost all /nbproject/ files and all /app/config/localdev.php as well !!!
And perhaps the others, but since they are autogenerated by php framework uppon runtime, I can't really tell!

3)
I then switch back to the **master branch** and I got those files there.

4)
I've copy those files somewhere else, and I've switched to **dev branch** again.

5)
I've place those missing files back inside /nbproject/ folder.

Now, if I try to switch to the Master branch, I'm getting this:

```
Error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:     
    nbproject/private/config.properties      
    nbproject/private/private.properties     
    nbproject/private/private.xml    
    nbproject/project.properties     
    nbproject/project.xml 

    Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.  

    Aborting
```

I'm aware that I should perhaps do a `git add .` to move those files on the repository, what I don't understand is:

Why is git throwing this message IF I had nbproject/ ignored well before those git checkout commands being issued?

Question:

The point is to ignore those files. Both on master and dev. My question is: how can I fix this in order to:

a) First:
**get those files (the ones on gitignore) back to dev ?**

b) Second:
**make steps to avoid this conflict again.**

Comment: The problem is that `master` is obviously tracking those files, not ignoring them, while `dev` is ignoring them and not tracking them. The best course of action depends on which of the two patterns is the "right" one for your project - either track the files or ignore them. Trying to do both on different branches causes these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps taken to solve the problem.
Credits go to: **jszakmeister**

**1)** I have cloned the project to somewhere else.

**2)** I've checkout master on that clone.

**3)** Placed the gitignore into the master as it should have been there from the beginning: 
     git show dev:.gitignore > .gitignore

**4)** I've removed the files from the tree by doing git rm "all files that where on gitignore one by one"

**5)** I've added the .gitignore file to the repo.

**6)** commit it

**7)** switch back to the original repo and did:

**8)** git fetch /path/to/fix-project master:master

**9)** git checkout master, and I got:
    Switched to branch 'master' 
    Your branch is ahead of 'hub/master' by 1 commit.
    this is my remote master branch.

**10)** Pushed to remote master.

**11)** checkout dev again

Answer (score 9):

You can track them in the other branch. Or, you can add `--force` to the checkout command to zap the files with what ever master has. Or, you can `git clean -xdf` before checking out master to zap the files from the working dir.

Comment: Those files that where on gitignore, have disapeared on my dev branch. I need to have them back from master to dev. But I can't checkout master. So what command should one type in order to have NOT all the master files back on dev but only the ones that where on gitignore

Comment: I don't understand what zap the file mean. So I can't follow your answer. Please, I've updated my question. Can you please clarify your answer ?

Comment: `git clean -xdf` can potentially delete files you might want. Try with `git clean -fdxn` to first check what's going to be deleted.

Comment: how does `--force` affect uncommitted changes in the destination branch that have no conflicts with current branch?

Comment: TG for the --force option - had to traverse every darn answer in 2 SO pages to overcome this error before I hit this option. Thanks ! Just wish git was more user friendly and showed this option when it fails. Wasted 2 hours on this ridiculous shyte on totally unnecessary jar files.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are having the scenario like below**:

You had merged child branch in the master branch. Then you try to pull the changes in the in the master branch.
Now when you are trying to switch your branch from child to master, you are experiencing the above issue i.e "**Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.**"

STEP 1: Backup all the listed files(in case Restore is not possible in your OS).

STEP 2: Delete the files which is responsible for the errors.

STEP 3: Switch the branch (Now no error will be thrown)

STEP 4: Restore the deleted files.

Happy Coding ;)